# How to install luidia ebeam software

Tags: software-installation

I have downloaded from Luidia, the ebeam interactive software for linux. The filename is "ebeamscrapbook_linux_ubuntu_1_0_0.tgz. I am running ubuntu 12.04. How can i install it?

Comment: Got it. Thank you. It was a self extracting file. I pressed run and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file extension `.tgz` is used for a certain archive type. You have to extract it (like a `.zip` on Windows).

The file(s) contained in the archive should be the installation files.